# Getting script like error when sending file from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, download, mime-types

I get this error when I try and send a file from my asp.net page :

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.**

My code :

// this gets triggered by a `linkButton` on a grid

```
    protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;

        // save file to temp
        Byte[] fileBytes = null;
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(lb.CommandArgument);
            fileBytes = db.Requests.Single(x => x.Id == id).File;
        }
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);

        // send
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        SendFile(fi);
    }

    private void SendFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();


// I also tried the code below I get the same error.

        //Response.Clear();
        //Response.ClearHeaders();
        //Response.ClearContent();
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PriceFile.zip");
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        //Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        //Response.Flush();
        //Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        //Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are sending the click event in update panel.
Try full page postback on Download button click event if you are using ajax

Comment: Thanks, I think you must of had the same issue to know I was using it inside an update panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear all the html content of your page, and left only the first line (page)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="download.aspx.vb" Inherits="download" %>
```